# How do I add an error band to a plot?

Tags: plotting

I have two plots, one generated with `Plot` and the other generated by `ListLinePlot`. Both plots look the same. I am trying to plot the error band of 5% around `Sin[[π x]`. How to do this?

I have tried `IntervalMarkers`, but that did not work.

```
Plot[Sin[π x], {x, 0, 1}]
x = Table[i, {i, 0, 1, 0.01}];
y = Table[Sin[π*x[[i]]], {i, 1, Length[x]}];
data = Transpose[{x, y}];
ListLinePlot[data]
```

I am trying to get something like this

[image: Expected result]

Comment: Can you show your attempt at `IntervalMarkers`?

Comment: `yy = Table[
  Quantity[Around[y[[i]] \[PlusMinus] 0.05*y[[i]], x[[i]]], 
   "USDollars"], {i, 1, Length[x]}]; ListLinePlot[prices, 
 IntervalMarkers -> "Bands", InterpolationOrder -> 3, 
 Sequence[PlotTheme -> "Scientific", PlotRange -> All]]`

Comment: Your syntax is off: The first argument of `Around` is the value, the second one should be the error. It doesn't understand ± for errors. Each data point should be `{x, Around[y, yerr]}`, so ` yy = Table[{x[[i]],Quantity[Around[y[[i]],0.05*y[[i]]],"USDollars"]},{i,1,Length[x]}]` does the trick.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`IntervalMarkers` and `Around` can be used in a much simpler and more concise way to generate the same plot as Lucas Lang gets. Like so:

```
ListLinePlot[Table[{i, With[{y = Sin[π i]}, Around[y, .05 y]]}, {i, 0, 1, 0.01}],
  IntervalMarkers -> "Bands",
  PlotTheme -> "Scientific"]
```

[image: plot]

Answer (score 3):

One way would be to use `Filling`.

```
data = Table[{x, Sin[Pi x]}, {x, 0, 2, 0.01}];
ndat = Length[data];
err = Table[0.2, {i,ndat}];(*you can get it from a list also*)
ListLinePlot[{
   Table[{data[[i, 1]], data[[i, 2]]}, {i, ndat}],
   Table[{data[[i, 1]], data[[i, 2]] + err[[i]]/2}, {i, ndat}],
   Table[{data[[i, 1]], data[[i, 2]] - err[[i]]/2}, {i, ndat}]},
PlotStyle -> {{Thick, Orange}, Orange, Orange},
Filling -> {2 -> {3}} (*from 2nd to third line*)
]
```

[image]

When error is a fraction of the y value

```
err = Table[(15/100)*data[[i, 2]], {i,ndat}];(*15%*)
ListLinePlot[{Table[{data[[i, 1]], data[[i, 2]]}, {i, ndat}], 
  Table[{data[[i, 1]], data[[i, 2]] + err[[i]]/2}, {i, ndat}], 
  Table[{data[[i, 1]], data[[i, 2]] - err[[i]]/2}, {i, ndat}]}, 
PlotStyle -> {{Thick, Orange}, Orange, Orange}, 
Filling -> {2 -> {3}}]
```

[image]

Comment: What is the percentage of error? Where you mentioned it?

Comment: I leave it to you ;). `err` is the table for the error.  I choose uniform error 0.2. You can make it a percentage of the y value, say, `0.05*data[[n,2]]` or a random number.

Answer (score 3):

*Note:* The code below is a fixed version of the attempt made by the OP (given in the comments of the question) without any additional changes. For a much cleaner solution, see [@m_goldberg's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/212870/36508) instead.

You can use [`IntervalMarkers`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/IntervalMarkers.html) and [`Around`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Around.html) like this:

```
x = Table[i, {i, 0, 1, 0.01}];
y = Table[Sin[π*x[[i]]], {i, 1, Length[x]}];
yy = Table[
  {x[[i]], Quantity[Around[y[[i]], 0.05*y[[i]]], "USDollars"]},
  {i, 1, Length[x]}];
ListLinePlot[yy, IntervalMarkers -> "Bands", InterpolationOrder -> 3, 
 Sequence[PlotTheme -> "Scientific", PlotRange -> All]]
```

[image]

Comment: Basically you have the right idea, but I don't understand why you introduced all the unneeded stuff into the code, like `Quantity` and `Sequence` and  options like `PlotRange` and `InterpolationOrder`. Sorry, but. because of these things I can't upvote this answer

Comment: @m_goldberg That's because I simply took the code OP gave in the comments of the question and made the minimum amount of changes to get it working (i.e. to demonstrate what was wrong with theirs, instead of showing completely different code) - but you are right, the code as is is not very nice. I have added a note saying as much to the answer.

Comment: OK, I now see you picked up the OP's code from a comment. I have upvoted.